# Struts 2 there's no action mapped

Tags: json, ajax, struts

I have a Struts 2 application where I'm creating a function Export to Excel. I am using a button that is not inside a `s:form tag`

```
    <button class="action-button" id = "exportToExcel" style="float: right;height: 2em;padding: 0 1em; margin-right: 2%;" onClick="exportTableToExcel()">Export to Excel</button>
```

In the exportTableToExcel() i'm making an ajax call to send html table(pivot report data) to be sent as json data.

In my ajax call the url is specified as :

```
url: './pivotSaveToExcelAction/createExcelReport.action'
```

The struts.xml entry is as follows:

```
<package name="pivotSaveToExcelAction" namespace="/pivotSaveToExcelAction" extends="json-default">
    <action name="createExcelReport" class="....PivotSaveToExcelAction">
        <result type="json"/>
    </action>
</package>
```

Can anyone tell me where i'm going wrong?
I get the error:

> There's no action mapped for namespace /reports/pivotTable/pivotSaveToExcelAction and action name createExcelReport.

Comment: Doesn't seem like there is, using `./` as a URL prefix means you're going after a URL in the current path, which in your case appears to be `reports`, whereas your action is *absolutely* located at `/pivotTable/pivotSaveToExcelAction`, which is what you should be using.

Comment: i have tried using /pivotTable/pivotSaveToExcelAction...it doesn't work..my namespace doesn't even have /pivotTable..should i be using it then?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't paying attention. It'd be `/pivotSaveToExcelAction/createExcelReport`, but you can read your config file as well as I can (well, apparently better ;) If this is throwing you off you might want to take a step back and make sure you're clear on how both S2 config works, and how web URLs work in general.

Comment: thanks! i have changed my ajax url call to       url: '/reports/pivotSaveToExcelAction/createExcelReport.action',
and made changes to my struts.xml namespace="/reports/pivotSaveToExcelAction" and it finally doesn't give any error in console. However the ajax call still does not take me to my struts action class

Comment: Then check your network tab, your routes, etc; I don't know why you're putting `reports` in there since it's nowhere in your config.